# View tag statistics, how many questions have been asked over time

Tags: feature-request, tags, statistics, revisions-list

I find Stack Overflow is a great place to measure programming statistics. If I want to look at the popularity of Scala vs Clojure vs Groovy, you can just look at the number of questions tagged of each. Could we see a line graph of how many questions a tag had over time? :D

It would be cool.

(Of course, there are tons of things to take into account. Looking at just Stack Overflow, you would think C# is way more popular than Java, but other statistics say otherwise. Still, it would be a nice feature to have.)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/662125/top-n-tags-relative-popularity-history?TopN=6&Since=2010-01-01#graph) for the task.

The results for the StackOverflow are these:

[image]

On the horizontal scale is their relative percentage compared to all questions in that month.

The query is parametrizable on that

- how many tags you want to see
- since when do you want to see the stats (by default 2010-01-01)

The query could be made better if it would show the history of the top tags *for the last month*, and not the top tags overall.

Comment: Today the SE query does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great feature to have. On the other hand it is also very suitable for a separate site that uses the Creative Commons Data Dump. Lagging a maximum of one month behind is probably acceptable.

I may construct such a site. But I don't promise anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

> [Interactive tag trend comparison page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41450/interactive-tag-trend-comparison-page)

Answer (score 1):

I've found this which allows you to run a query to calculate this sort of thing. I don't really know much more about it. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/38106/tag-statistics

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if such a statistic necessarily represents the popularity of something. It could also be taken as a hint that something has more questions because it is harder to understand.

Comment: how the statistics should be interpreted is a slightly different (but relevant) issue. Its still information I would like to see. :D