# Question Trends analytics

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, questions

I would really like a feature that will show me the trends on questions asked say, last week, last month, and so forth.

For example: I don't see as many asp.net MVC questions as before, whereas I am seeing many more questions about JavaScript frameworks.

It would be really nice to see a trend on questions. It can be based on tags. Some cool analytics would be nice too. IMO, it would give me an idea on the topics being popular lately and I'm interested in that.

What do you think? Is there such a feature?

Comment: Even though it's not directly useful (as I'm sure many people are about to point out), it'd be a nice feature to have. Hell, even Google has word usage and search trends now, and they don't really _need_ to make that public.

Comment: I think it would be useful in the sense that we can see where trends are going. Do you have a such source any where? I dont think so. SO can do that.

Comment: I don't think StackExchange has an existing feature for this. It would be theoretically possible to pull the information out of the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and plot it in Excel, but that's not an insignificant amount of work.

Comment: Greg Hewgill built something like this a little while ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23554/tag-trends-by-week . His interactive [tag trend grapher](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/) looks like it might not be up to date through 2013, though.

Comment: @BradLarson Not useful at all. in that case, i need to know what I am searching for so i can find a graph what I was asking is some aggregator that will give me the graph\ and I am too lazy to do any work.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31762/view-tag-statistics-how-many-questions-have-been-asked-over-time