# How can I query SEDE to see the number of questions for a specific tag per year?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, statistics

Having in mind a specific tag from Stack Overflow (i.e. python). Is there any query to make in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) which could provide the number of questions and answers posted per year in the specific tag?

Comment: a query for the total number of question for a specific tag `SELECT Count From Tags Where TagName = 'python'`

Comment: Some queries with statistics about tags can also be seen here: [View tag statistics, how many questions have been asked over time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31762). (Although they are a bit different from what you asked for.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1576730/number-of-questions-and-answers-in-a-specific-tag-per-year?TagName=python#graph) is an attempt:

[image]